# Is it possible to have a placeholder text for p:selectOneMenu?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My question pretty much says everything. I want to have a placeholder text in the selectOneMenu, but I don't think there is any attribute to specify it. So how is it possible to have a placeholder?

I tried using a `<p:watermark>` as shown below, but it did not work.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="fooMenu">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="foo" itemValue="foo"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="goo" itemValue="goo"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:watermark value="Select" for="fooMenu"></p:watermark>
```

Comment: watermark is not meeting your requirement or watermark is not working as it is expected to be ?  what exactly is your requirement of placeholder text ?

Comment: I would have been relieved if Watermark had worked, but it is not. And according to http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3919, we cannot have watermark for Select elements. So I am looking for an alternative.

Comment: Well, watermark on `selectOneMenu` would be like additional select item, "Please select an item...". I don't see why you can't just add an item with empty value?

Comment: you can add one item "select an item" with noSelectionOption="true" param of <f:selectItem>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's indeed by default not supported on standard HTML `<select>` element, so there's also nothing in JSF to set that.

You can however *simulate* one with help of `itemDisabled` and a little bit of CSS and jQuery.

```
<p:selectOneMenu widgetVar="menu" styleClass="with-placeholder" panelStyleClass="hide-disabled" onchange="menu.jq.removeClass('with-placeholder')">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemDisabled="true" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="foo" itemValue="foo"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="goo" itemValue="goo"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

and

```css
.ui-selectonemenu.with-placeholder .ui-selectonemenu-label {
    color: #ccc;
}
.ui-selectonemenu-panel.hide-disabled .ui-selectonemenu-list-item.ui-state-disabled {
    display: none;
}
```

Here's a [video demo](http://www.screencast.com/t/oEi0CsxGkQq).

Comment: I have tried this and it works. But I need to do a server side validation if the user clicks Submit when the page is opened for the first time and 'Select' acts as a simulated placeholder. It results in the text 'Select' to be submitted as an item, which I absolutely do not want.

Comment: Just use `required="true"` the usual way. Its value is `null` anyway.

Comment: This is awesome, however in primefaces 5.1 it results in the need to click a select item twice.